# Meaning of instance

Tags: oop, object, reference, instance

What is the meaning of instance in programming sense? Please explain with example. Also, what is the meaning of the below lines?

I am writing the below code:

```
MyClass obj;
```

Now, I say that "`obj` is the reference to an instance of `MyClass`."

While I say the above line, I can not understand the meaning of the line "reference to an instance of `MyClass`." Does this mean that `obj` is the reference to an object of `MyClass`?

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code.

Comment: No... I have mentioned the code in bold letters... its MyClass obj;

Comment: When I do `var x = new Something();` I *instantiate* a `Something`. The object *referred to* by the variable `x` is the *instance* of `Something` that I *instantiated*. I might have other *instances* of the same class referred to by other variables.

Comment: @Ant P : Thanks for the answer. But, I want to know the meaning of instance. As you said that the object referred to by the variable x is the instance of Something that I instantiated. I want to understand the meaning of instance. I am not clear with this word.

Comment: Class is a blueprint for an object. An instance is an actual object created out from that blueprint. A reference is like a pointer to that instance created in the memory.

Comment: @SubhojeetChatterjee the phrases "object of type x" and "instance of x" are synonymous. An instance of something is just one of that thing.

Answer (score 3):

"Instance" (of a class) is simply another way to say "object".

Answer (score 3):

**Class:** 
In a class-paradigm language such as Java, a class is a template.  It is a series of instructions to the operating environment that enable it to construct and use objects.  The class defines its *members* in its definition file.  The members of a class in Java are its:

- *fields*: variables that store the variables that make up the state of a class
- *methods*: function definitions that define the behaviors that characterize the class
- *nested classes*: a class can define other classes inside it
- *nested interfaces*: a class can also define interfaces inside it

**Instance:**
An instance is an actual representation of a class.  This representation in memory can be called either an object or a class instance (or more simply, just instance).

To make this more concrete, lets look at class MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myField1;
    private String myField2;

    public MyClass(int f1, String f2) {
        this.myField1 = f1;
        this.myField2 = f2;
    }
    :
    :
}
```

MyClass is a class that defines two *instance fields* that contain the state information for every MyClass object that is created (myField1 and myField2).  It also defines a *Constructor* which instructs Java on how build a MyClass object. Here the constructor takes two parameters and uses them to initialize the instance fields.

This code:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(7, "Hello");
```

This statement *instantiates* a new instance of a `MyClass` object using the constructor MyClass(int, String).  The instance that is created will have `myField1` = 7 and `myField2` = "Hello".  Finally, a reference that points to the object that was instantiated is assigned to the variable `obj`.  In Java, all objects are *reference types*. An object can never be stored into a variable.  Instead, a pointer (or reference) to the object's location in memory is stored in the variable.

TLDR: The class is a template for a group of related objects.  An instance is an actual representation of the class, built using its template.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two apples on the counter, each is an instance of an apple. If you have a program with three variables with the numbers 1, 2, and 3, each variable is an instance of an integer.

An instance is just a specific version of an abstract thing. When you create a class, and make an object from that class, the object is one instance. If you make three objects all from your class, you have three instances.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `MyClass obj = new MyClass()`, you create an instance.

> the obj is the reference to an instance of MyClass

Perhaps that is the most correct way of saying, but colloquially, I would just say that `obj` is an instance of the class `MyClass`.

Forget about what instance is supposed to mean in the CS world. Think about the meaning of the word in English.

> an example or single occurrence of something.

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are instances of the class since they are simply an occurrence of it.

We say "reference", because the variable is just a symbol that refers to the actual instance. Like when `int x = 5`, `x` is not technically 5, it's just a symbol that refers to that value.

Comment: `obj1 and obj2 are instances of the class since they are simply an occurrence of it.` Not of the class. They are the references to the instances of the class

Comment: Does my clarification at the end explain that? I started with a simplification and then explained why we say "reference". Or should I reword the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let's illustrate all this without staying too abstract:

- A class defines a concept.
- An instance is a concrete, real incarnation of that concept.

eg.

- A keyboard is something where I can press letters (a concept)
- The particular keyboard I am typing this answer on is a concrete, real incarnation of a keyboard (an instance)

When you **say**:

```
class MyClass {
  void method1() { ... }
}
```

You define how an object defined by MyClass looks like and behaves

When you **do**:

```
MyClass obj;
```

You actually create an object corresponding to that definition

Answer (score 0):

An instance is simply an object. Let's say you have the following:

```
class Car
{
    int nWheels;
}

Car c = new Car();
```

In this Java snippet, you have a class `Car`, and are creating a variable called `c`, which is a reference to a `Car`. Now in popular languages such as C++ and Java, the keyword `new` means "create an *instance* (aka object) of the given class, and give me a *reference* to it", which is why `c` is a reference. When a variable is a reference, it is basically just a memory address of where the actual instance/object is in memory (references are actually more, but you can think of it this way), and not the actual instance itself. Because of this, you can have multiple references to the same object, change one, and they all change.

Suppose you have the code

```
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car();
```

then both `car1` and `car2` are *references* to separate instances, since they each used a constructor. But if you did,

```
car2 = car1;
```

then `car2` and `car1` are still both references, but they both reference the same instance (the object created by the line `Car car1 = new Car();`, and nothing is referencing the object created in the line `Car car2 = new Car();`.

Answer (score -1):

An instance means as it is in the English dictionary: *"an example or single occurrence of something".*

Cookie example (I read it somewhere):

*Would you like a cookie for desert?*

Cookie is an instance of a **class** desert.